# How can I create a table with borders in Android?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I use a table layout to display data as table, but I want a table with user-defined columns and rows with borders.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 204):

My solution for this problem is to put an xml drawable resource on the background field of every cell. In this manner you could define a shape with the border you want for all cells. The only inconvenience is that the borders of the extreme cells have half the width of the others but it's no problem if your table fills the entire screen.

*An Example:*

drawable/cell_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
        <solid android:color="#000"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#ff9"/>
</shape>
```

layout/my_table.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tabla_cabecera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabla_cuerpo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: An example

[image]

Edit2: Another example (with more elements: circle corners, gradients...)
[image]

I have explained this issue with more details in http://blog.intelligenia.com/2012/02/programacion-movil-en-android.html#more. It's in spanish but there are some codes and images of more complex tables.

Comment: i am not able to view the content

Comment: How would I set the background of the view programmatically?
`view.setBackground(?)`

Comment: In order to view this, just delete the first row called tabla_cabecera

Comment: This will make the borders appear at least 2px thick which isn't as nice as a 1px width border.

Comment: Yes, as I explained it is the only inconvenience, but if your table fills the entire screen you can set bottom and left borders to 1px (for example) and you will a table with 1px borders.

Comment: The only issue here is that the in-between borderlines get thicker for multiple rows(It happened due to overlapping of borders). To solve this add android:background="@drawable/border" at TableLayout & also in TableRows but alternatively(i.e, add background at 2nd,4th,6th... TableRow).

Answer (score 56):

I have to agree with Brad. That was an awful answer. The Android documentation states that TableLayout containers do not display border lines, so sending them to the Android site wont help them a bit. I was able to find a "dirty" solution on droidnova, which involves setting a background color for the TableLayout, then setting a different background color for the TableRow and adding layout_margin to the row.  I'm not fond of this solution, but  it does work for row borders.  I guess you could do the same thing with the items composing each "cell" item but I haven't verified.

An example similar to the one on DroidNova:

```
<TableLayout android:background="#000000"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFF"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="1dp">
     ...
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Beware the deliberate overdraw issue here, it may cause janking / stuttering in the UI if the table is large.

Comment: How can I set layout_margin programmatically on `TableRow` object?

Comment: it just adds outline around table and its rows but not between columns

Answer (score 41):

***IF*** you are just trying to have a line in between rows (for example, just above a "Total" row) then there is an easy solution - just add a TableRow with a background color and a specific layout_height such as this:

```
<TableRow android:layout_height="1px" android:background="#BDBDBD">
   <TextView android:layout_span="2" android:layout_height="1px" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="">
   </TextView>
</TableRow>
```

Set `android:layout_height="1px"` or however thick you want the border to be.  Fill in as many empty TextView columns as you need to match the rest of your table, or just use one along with [`android:layout_span`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html) as I have demonstrated.

The output will look something like this:

[image: Table Border demonstrated]

If you are trying to add more complicated borders then the other answers already posted are more appropriate.

Comment: why a `TextView` when you can use a `View` instead? Also it isn't good practice to specify exact pixels. Use dp/sp instead. See also this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android/2025541#2025541.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...   No reason to use TextView I suppose - it was just an example.  Second, unless I am misunderstanding dp/sp (fairly likely, actually, since I've only been developing on Android for about a week) I use px because I only want a guaranteed-1-pixel line between my rows, no matter what resolution or screen size I'm using.  I like very thin lines.  Other users may have different tastes and use other units.

Comment: yes but do you like very thin lines ! - that said good simple solution  gets my vote

Answer (score 26):

What I wanted is a table like this

[image: table image with vertical dividers]

I added this in my **styles.xml** :

```
      <style name="Divider">
        <item name="android:layout_width">1dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Divider_invisible">
        <item name="android:layout_width">1dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    </style>
```

Then in my **table layout** :

```
 <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#92C94A" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <View style="@style/Divider_invisible" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/main_wo_colon"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <View style="@style/Divider" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/side_wo_colon"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <View style="@style/Divider" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/total"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <!-- display this button in 3rd column via layout_column(zero based) -->

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#6F9C33" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView21"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/servings"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <View style="@style/Divider" />
                </LinearLayout>

..........
.......
......
```

Answer (score 25):

You can also do this progamatically, rather than through xml, but it's a bit more "hackish". But give a man no options and you leave him no choice :p.. Here's the code:

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
tr.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2); //Border between rows

TableRow.LayoutParams llp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llp.setMargins(0, 0, 2, 0);//2px right-margin

//New Cell
LinearLayout cell = new LinearLayout(this);
cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
cell.setLayoutParams(llp);//2px border on the right for the cell


TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Some Text");
tv.setPadding(0, 0, 4, 3);

cell.addView(tv);
tr.addView(cell);
//add as many cells you want to a row, using the same approach

table.addView(tr);
```

Answer (score 16):

To make 1dp collapse-border around every cell without writing a java code and without creating another xml layout with `<shape...>` tag, you can try this solution:

In `<TableLayout...>` add
`android:background="#CCC"` and `android:paddingTop="1dp"` and `android:stretchColumns="0"`

In `<TableRow...>` add
`android:background="#CCC"` and `android:paddingBottom="1dp"` and `android:paddingRight="1dp"`

In every cell/child in TableRow, i.e. `<TextView...>` add
`android:background="#FFF"` and `android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"`

It is very important to follow paddings and margins as described. This solution will draw a 1dp border aka border-collapse property in (X)HTML/CSS.

Background color in `<TableLayout...>` and `<TableRow...>` represents a border line color and background in `<TextView...>` fills a table cell. You can put some padding in cells if necessary.

An example is here:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCC"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:stretchColumns="0"
    android:id="@+id/tlTable01">

    <TableRow
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Item1"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="123456"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Item2"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="456789"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks!

Comment: This is good, but there is a problem when you would like to use dark mode. Because you have to put into TableRow background = white to have white borders. And now when your second TextView will be longer (higher) than first TextView you will have white background behind first TextView. Setting background to dark for first TextView will not help because it will not cover the whole view.

Comment: This is what i was looking for... Thanks Also what @WiktorKalinowski said is also true for dark mode we have to play around manually.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Here i have designed the list by the following design image. My listitem filename is **Propertylistitem.xml** and **cellborder.xml** is used drawable shape for the cellborder output, are show in this image. necessary code i added here.

**FileName:propertylistitem.xml**

```
<TableLayout... >
            <TableRow... >
                 <TextView ...
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:text="Amount"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow... >
                <TextView...
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:text="5000"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

**filename:cellborder.xml** 
Here i just want only border in my design, so i put comment the solid color tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <!--     <solid android:color="#dc6888"/>     -->
        <stroke android:width="0.1dp" android:color="#ffffff"
            />
        <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 10):

After long  search and hours of trying this is the simplest code i could make:

```
ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
border.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
border.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
tv.setBackground(border);
content.addView(tv);
```

tv is a TextView with a simple text and content is my container (LinearLayout in this Case).
That's a little easier.

Comment: requires API lvl 16 :(

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable()` can be used instead.

Answer (score 10):

Well  that may inspire u 
Those steps show **how to create bordered table dynamically**

here is the table view

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:scrollingCache="true">
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/simpleTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
    </TableLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and here the row to use **"attrib_row.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/attrib_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/attrib_value"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        />
</TableRow>
```

and we can add this xml file to drawable to add border to our table **"border.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

and finally here is the compact code written in **Kotlin** but it's easy to convert it to java if you need

well temps is an array list  contain data: `ArrayList<Double>()`

```
fun CreateTable()
{
    val temps=controller?.getTemps()
    val rowHead = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.attrib_row, null) as TableRow
    (rowHead.findViewById<View>(R.id.attrib_name) as TextView).text=("time")
    (rowHead.findViewById<View>(R.id.attrib_value) as TextView).text=("Value")
    table!!.addView(rowHead)
    for (i in 0 until temps!!.size) {

        val row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.attrib_row, null) as TableRow
        (row.findViewById<View>(R.id.attrib_name) as TextView).text=((i+1).toString())
        (row.findViewById<View>(R.id.attrib_value) as TextView).text=(temps[i].toString())
        table!!.addView(row)
    }
    table!!.requestLayout()
}
```

and you can use it in your **fragment** for example like this

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        table = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.simpleTableLayout) as TableLayout
        CreateTable()
    }
```

the final result looks like this 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

How about overriding the onDraw method and then painting lines to the canvas?

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * m_cellHeight, m_totalWidth, i * m_cellHeight, paint);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m_columns; i++){
        canvas.drawLine(i* m_cellWidth, 0, i * m_cellWidth, m_cellHeight * rows, paint);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need table with the border, I suggest linear layout with weight instead of TableLayout.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="PRODUCT"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingStart="1dp"
    android:paddingEnd="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chainprod"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/pdct"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chainthick"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/thcns"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chainsize"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/size" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/sqft" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingStart="1dp"
    android:paddingEnd="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewchainprod"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/pdct" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewchainthick"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/thcns"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewchainsize"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/size"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewchainsqft"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/sqft"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I used this solution: in `TableRow`, I created for every cell `LinearLayout` with vertical line and actual cell in it, and after every `TableRow`, I added a horizontal line.

Look at the code below:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="1">

    <TableRow            
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <View
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="#BDCAD2"/>

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>
      </TableRow>

      <View
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#BDCAD2" />

      <!-- More TableRows -->
</TableLayout>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: This is a simple approach for adding a single line below the row.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great way to solve this problem:

Create a rectangle drawable with rounded corners like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#888888"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="6dp" 
             android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp" 
             android:topLeftRadius="6dp" 
             android:topRightRadius="6dp"/> 
</shape>
```

save it in the drawable folder with the name rounded_border.xml

Then create a relative layout that uses the rounded_border as a background like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border">
   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/list_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

save that in your layout folder and name it table_with_border.xml

then whenever you need such a table pull it into a view using the include syntax like this:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/rounded_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/table_with_border" />
```

You will probably want to add some spacing around the edges - so just wrap the include in a LinearLayout and add some padding around the edges.

Simple and easy way to get a pretty border around a table.

Answer (score 2):

The stroke doubles up on the middel sections, I used this layer list drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">

     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp">

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/lightgrey" />
    </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to create 1px nine-patch image, and use showDividers attribute in TableRow and TableLayout since they are both LinearLayouts

Comment: Can you give a simple example on it?

Answer (score 2):

A border between cells is doubled in above answers.
So, you can try this solution:

```
<item
    android:left="-1dp"
    android:top="-1dp">

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ccc"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use linear layouts and set dividers between rows and cells like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="#8000"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/border"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8000"
        android:layout_marginTop="1px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1px"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/border"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8000"
        android:layout_marginTop="1px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1px"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/border"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8000"
        android:layout_marginTop="1px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1px"/>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="#8000"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/border"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8000"
        android:layout_marginTop="1px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1px"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/border"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8000"
        android:layout_marginTop="1px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1px"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/border"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8000"
        android:layout_marginTop="1px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1px"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="#8000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It's a dirty solution, but it's simple and also works with transparent background and borders.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question ... anyway ... if you want to keep your xml nice and simple you can extend TableLayout and override dispatchDraw to do some custom drawing.

Here is a quick and dirty implementation that draws a rectangle around the table view as well as horizontal and verticals bars:

```
public class TableLayoutEx extends TableLayout {
    private Paint linePaint = null;
    private Rect tableLayoutRect;

    public TableLayoutEx(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TableLayoutEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        float strokeWidth = this.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity * 1;
        linePaint = new Paint(0);
        linePaint.setColor(0xff555555);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Rect rect = new Rect();           
        int paddingTop= getPaddingTop();

        this.getDrawingRect(rect);
        tableLayoutRect = new Rect(rect.left, rect.top + paddingTop, rect.right, rect.bottom);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        Rect rect = new Rect();

        if (linePaint != null) {
            canvas.drawRect(tableLayoutRect, linePaint);
            float y = tableLayoutRect.top;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount() - 1; i++) {
                if (getChildAt(i) instanceof TableRow) {
                    TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) getChildAt(i);
                    tableRow.getDrawingRect(rect);
                    y += rect.height();
                    canvas.drawLine(tableLayoutRect.left, y, tableLayoutRect.right, y, linePaint);
                    float x = tableLayoutRect.left;
                    for (int j = 0; j < tableRow.getChildCount() - 1; j++) {
                        View view = tableRow.getChildAt(j);
                        if (view != null) {
                            view.getDrawingRect(rect);
                            x += rect.width();
                            canvas.drawLine(x, tableLayoutRect.top, x, tableLayoutRect.bottom, linePaint);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xml example with the third column wrapping text:

```
<com.YOURPACKAGE.TableLayoutEx
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="2"
    android:paddingTop="6dp">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/my_text_0_0"
            android:padding="@dimen/my_padding"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/my_text_0_1"
            android:padding="@dimen/my_padding"/>
        <TextView                   
            android:text="@string/my_text_0_2_to_wrap"
            android:padding="@dimen/my_padding"/>
    </TableRow>

    <!--more table rows here-->

</com.YOURPACKAGE.TableLayoutEx>
```