# How to draw a line in an IF statement for java

Tags: java, android, if-statement, line

I am trying to program an androd application where if there is input on two places of the screen in sucsession then it will draw a line between the two points. I have already set up "X" and "Y" values that work and columns and rows are defined by the "X" and "Y" values. After those i have an IF statement that needs to draw a line between the two points. Say if column one and row two are selected and then colum one and row three are selcted I want a line to be drawn between the two points. Also I am not totally sure how to use the MotionEvent stuff or how to put the touch actions into the IF statement.

```
     final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override         
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
            String.valueOf(event.getX() + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
        double c = event.getX();
        double column = Math.floor(event.getX()/(480/12));
        double r = event.getY();
        double row = Math.floor(event.getY()/(630/12));


    if (column == 0 && row == 2 //there should be more stuff here 
                   ) {
                  //I dont know how to draw a line in here, please help
    }
        return true;     
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: see this thread: [How to draw line in android.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than explain the details here, I'll point you to these pieces of sample code from the `ApiDemos` sample project that comes with the SDK, that probably do exactly what you want:

- [DrawPoints.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/DrawPoints.html)
- [TouchPaint.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html)

The basic idea is to store X and Y coordinates in your touch event handler, invalidate the `View`, and then draw the lines in the `onDraw` method using `Canvas` operations such as `drawLine`.

Comment: Thank you, but what and where do you get the Graphics Activity that gets extended, but if you dont need that then what do you do. Sorry that I need so much help, but if you cant tell, I am really new.

Comment: `GraphicsActivity` is also in the ApiDemos sample app: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/GraphicsActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

You do neew to have a tool to draw the line, most suitable for you it seems to be Canvas. If you don't know anything about Canvas together with Android yet i suggest you to look into some examles that Android leaves us. Ones you have done that, this is going to be a simple task.

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but where did android leave us these examples ?

Comment: Well, i don't remember if there's any example online at http://developer.android.com/index.html . There may be but however, there is in the samples directory in your'e android sdk. For example Lunar-Lander, that is a game using Canvas in android.