# Draw lines in Activity who extends from 'Activity'

Tags: android, android-activity, lines

i have an activity with buttons, textviews, and so on.
all i want is to draw some lines inside this activity.

is this possible? if yes, how?

can someone give me a tip?

thanks, prexx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing takes place inside of views, You should override onDraw method of the view you are going to draw on. Also you could check following [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)