# How to draw a triangle, a star, a square or a heart on the canvas?

Tags: android, draw, shapes

I am able to draw a circle and a rectangle on canvas by using
`path.addCircle()`

and

`path.addRect()`.

And now I am wondering how to draw a triangle or a star or  a square or a heart?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to find out the math behind that figures. The triangle and the star are quite easy to draw. Here is how you can draw a heart: http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/heart.htm

To draw special paths you should create them by adding points, ellipses etc. The canvas supports a clipping mask of a specified path, so you can set the clipping mask of a heart, push the paths to the matrix, draw the content of the heart, and then pop it again.

That's what I'm doing to achieve a simulated 2D page curl effect on andriod: http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 32):

For future direct answer seekers, I have drawn an almost symmetric star using canvas, as shown in the image:

[image: Star Image]

The main tool is using Paths.

Assuming you have setup:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

Path path = new Path();
```

Then in you onDraw you can use the path like I do below. It will scale properly to any sizes canvas

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    float mid = getWidth() / 2;
    float min = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
    float fat = min / 17;
    float half = min / 2;
    float rad = half - fat;
    mid = mid - half;

    paint.setStrokeWidth(fat);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.drawCircle(mid + half, half, rad, paint);

    path.reset();

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);


        // top left
        path.moveTo(mid + half * 0.5f, half * 0.84f);
        // top right
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.5f, half * 0.84f);
        // bottom left
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 0.68f, half * 1.45f);
        // top tip
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.0f, half * 0.5f);
        // bottom right
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.32f, half * 1.45f);
        // top left
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 0.5f, half * 0.84f);

        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    super.onDraw(canvas);

}
```

Comment: Good Answer! Thanks!  I think `path.lineTo(mid + half * 0.5f, half * 0.84f);` in the end (before path close) not needed as `path.close()` will handle that automatically!

Answer (score 14):

For everybody that needs a heart shape:

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.view.View;

    public class Heart extends View {

        private Path path;

        private Paint paint;

        public Heart(Context context) {
            super(context);

            path = new Path();
            paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);

                // Fill the canvas with background color
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                paint.setShader(null);

                float width = getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.heart_width);
                float height = getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.heart_height);

                // Starting point
                path.moveTo(width / 2, height / 5); 

                // Upper left path
                path.cubicTo(5 * width / 14, 0,
                        0, height / 15,
                        width / 28, 2 * height / 5);

                // Lower left path
                path.cubicTo(width / 14, 2 * height / 3,
                        3 * width / 7, 5 * height / 6,
                        width / 2, height);

                // Lower right path
                path.cubicTo(4 * width / 7, 5 * height / 6,
                        13 * width / 14, 2 * height / 3,
                        27 * width / 28, 2 * height / 5);

                // Upper right path
                path.cubicTo(width, height / 15,
                        9 * width / 14, 0,
                        width / 2, height / 5);

                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

            }
    }
```

Sorry for all the numbers but these worked best for me :) The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

this method will return a path with the number of corners given inside a square of the given width. Add more parameters to handle small radius and such things.

```
    private Path createStarBySize(float width, int steps) {
    float halfWidth = width / 2.0F;
    float bigRadius = halfWidth;
    float radius = halfWidth / 2.0F;
    float degreesPerStep = (float) Math.toRadians(360.0F / (float) steps);
    float halfDegreesPerStep = degreesPerStep / 2.0F;
    Path ret = new Path();
    ret.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    float max = (float) (2.0F* Math.PI);
    ret.moveTo(width, halfWidth);
    for (double step = 0; step < max; step += degreesPerStep) {
        ret.lineTo((float)(halfWidth + bigRadius * Math.cos(step)), (float)(halfWidth + bigRadius * Math.sin(step)));
        ret.lineTo((float)(halfWidth + radius * Math.cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep)), (float)(halfWidth + radius * Math.sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep)));
    }
    ret.close();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Answered to my own question, to set the star pointing north: 1. Set FillType.WINDING. 2. Set max to (2 * PI - PI / 2). 3. Set ret.moveTo(halfWidth, 0).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to draw a star inside a square, you can use the code below.

`posX` and `posY` are the coordinates for the upper left corner of the square that encloses the tips of the star (the square is not actually drawn).

`size` is the width and height of the square.

`a` is the top tip of the star. The path is created clockwise.

This is by no means a perfect solution, but it gets the job done very quickly.

```
 public void drawStar(float posX, float posY, int size, Canvas canvas){

            int hMargin = size/9;
            int vMargin = size/4;

            Point a = new Point((int) (posX + size/2), (int) posY);
            Point b = new Point((int) (posX + size/2 + hMargin), (int) (posY + vMargin));
            Point c = new Point((int) (posX + size), (int) (posY + vMargin));
            Point d = new Point((int) (posX + size/2 + 2*hMargin), (int) (posY + size/2 + vMargin/2));
            Point e = new Point((int) (posX + size/2 + 3*hMargin), (int) (posY + size));
            Point f = new Point((int) (posX + size/2), (int) (posY + size - vMargin));
            Point g = new Point((int) (posX + size/2 - 3*hMargin), (int) (posY + size));
            Point h = new Point((int) (posX + size/2 - 2*hMargin), (int) (posY + size/2 + vMargin/2));
            Point i = new Point((int) posX, (int) (posY + vMargin));
            Point j = new Point((int) (posX + size/2 - hMargin), (int) (posY + vMargin));

            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
            path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
            path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
            path.lineTo(d.x, d.y);
            path.lineTo(e.x, e.y);
            path.lineTo(f.x, f.y);
            path.lineTo(f.x, f.y);
            path.lineTo(g.x, g.y);
            path.lineTo(h.x, h.y);
            path.lineTo(i.x, i.y);
            path.lineTo(j.x, j.y);
            path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);

            path.close();

            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ellipse and rectangular you will need those two (as minimum):

[drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)
[drawLines(float[] pts, int offset, int count, Paint paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLines%28float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

example:
[How to draw a line in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android)

Documentation on Canvas: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: You need to divide complex shapes to primitive ones. For example you can draw heart using two half circles and two lines. Triangle - select 3 points and connect them with drawLine() or even better pass array pf points to drawLines();

Answer (score 0):

**Its very good to use instance of Shape class ))**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    HeartShape shape = new HeartShape();
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(shape);
    shapeDrawable.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0, Color.BLUE));

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(350 * 3, 350 * 3));
    linearLayout.setBackground(shapeDrawable);

    setContentView(linearLayout);
  }
```

Create a shape class which was render nice Heart

```
 public class HeartShape extends Shape {

  private final int INVALID_SIZE = -1;

  private Path mPath = new Path();
  private RectF mRectF = new RectF();

  private float mOldWidth = INVALID_SIZE;
  private float mOldHeight = INVALID_SIZE;

  private float mScaleX, mScaleY;

  public HeartShape() {

  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(mScaleX, mScaleY);

    float width = mRectF.width();
    float height = mRectF.height();

    float halfWidth = width/2;
    float halfHeight = height/2;

    float stdDestX = 5 * width / 14;
    float stdDestY = 2 * height / 3;

    PointF point1 = new PointF(stdDestX, 0);
    PointF point2 = new PointF(0, height / 15);
    PointF point3 = new PointF(stdDestX / 5, stdDestY);
    PointF point4 = new PointF(stdDestX, stdDestY);

    // Starting point
    mPath.moveTo(halfWidth, height / 5);

    mPath.cubicTo(point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y, width / 28, 2 * height / 5);
    mPath.cubicTo(point3.x, point3.y, point4.x, point4.y, halfWidth, height);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);

    canvas.scale(-mScaleX, mScaleY, halfWidth, halfHeight);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);

    canvas.restore();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResize(float width, float height) {
    mOldWidth = mOldWidth == INVALID_SIZE ? width : Math.max(1, mOldWidth);
    mOldHeight = mOldHeight == INVALID_SIZE ? height : Math.max(1, mOldHeight);

    width = Math.max(1, width);
    height = Math.max(1, height);

    mScaleX = width / mOldWidth;
    mScaleY = height / mOldHeight;

    mOldWidth = width;
    mOldHeight = height;


    mRectF.set(0, 0, width, height);
  }

  @Override
  public void getOutline(@NonNull Outline outline) {
    // HeartShape not supported outlines
  }

  @Override
  public HeartShape clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    HeartShape shape = (HeartShape) super.clone();
    shape.mPath = new Path(mPath);
    return shape;
  }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to draw only the shapes you specify I recommend first creat a class for each shape and make each shape implement ***draw()*** method where you can pass canvas and paint object.

[image]

For example to create multiple stars, first create a class "Star" and implement the logic there.

```
class Star(
        var cx: Float = 0f,
        var cy: Float = 0f,
        var radius: Float = 0f,
        var angle: Float = 0f,
        var color: Int = Color.WHITE,
        var numberOfSpikes: Int = 5,
        var depth: Float = 0.4f
    ) {

        val path: Path = Path()
        val point: PointF = PointF()

        fun init() {
            path.rewind()

            var totalAngle = 0f
            for (i in 0 until numberOfSpikes * 2) {

                val x = cx
                var y = cy
                y -= if (i % 2 != 0) (radius * depth)
                else (radius * 1f)

                StaticMethods.rotate(cx, cy, x, y, totalAngle, false, point)
                totalAngle += 360f / (numberOfSpikes * 2)
                if (i == 0) {
                    path.moveTo(point.x, point.y)
                } else {
                    path.lineTo(point.x, point.y)
                }
            }
        }

        fun draw(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {

            paint.apply {
                style = Paint.Style.FILL
                color = this@Star.color
            }
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        }
    }


object StaticMethods {
    
 /**
     * Rotate a point around a center with given angle
     * @param cx rotary center point x coordinate
     * @param cy rotary center point y coordinate
     * @param x x coordinate of the point that will be rotated
     * @param y y coordinate of the point that will be rotated
     * @param angle angle of rotation in degrees
     * @param anticlockWise rotate clockwise or anti-clockwise
     * @param resultPoint object where the result rotational point will be stored
     */
    fun rotate(cx: Float, cy: Float, x: Float, y: Float, angle: Float, anticlockWise: Boolean = false, resultPoint: PointF = PointF()): PointF {

        if (angle == 0f) {
            resultPoint.x = x
            resultPoint.y = y
            return resultPoint
        }

        val radians = if (anticlockWise) {
            (Math.PI / 180) * angle
        } else {
            (Math.PI / -180) * angle
        }

        val cos = Math.cos(radians)
        val sin = Math.sin(radians)
        val nx = (cos * (x - cx)) + (sin * (y - cy)) + cx
        val ny = (cos * (y - cy)) - (sin * (x - cx)) + cy

        resultPoint.x = nx.toFloat()
        resultPoint.y = ny.toFloat()
        return resultPoint
    }
    /**
     * Inline function that is called, when the final measurement is made and
     * the view is about to be draw.
     */
    inline fun View.afterMeasured(crossinline function: View.() -> Unit) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    function()
                }
            }
        })
     }
}
```

And then create a custom view where you can draw your shapes, below is the code that creates 100 random stars and draws them on canvas.

```
class StarView : View {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    val stars: ArrayList<Helper.Star> = arrayListOf()

    val paint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    init {

        // after the view is measured and we have the width and height
        afterMeasured {

            // create 100 stars
            for (i in 0 until 100) {

                val star = Helper.Star(
                    cx = width * Math.random().toFloat(),
                    cy = height * Math.random().toFloat(),
                    radius = width * 0.1f * Math.random().toFloat(),
                )
                star.init()
                stars.add(star)
            }
        }

    }


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        stars.forEach {
            it.draw(canvas, paint)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

---

If you want to create a lot of different complex shapes you can use this [library](https://github.com/slaviboy/SVGPathKotlin). Where you can pass svg shapes using the Path Data as a string. By first creating complex shapes using any SVG vector editor such as

- Microsoft Expression Design
- Adobe Illustrator
- Inkscape

---