# Getting the width/height of a layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm wondering how to measure the dimensions of a view. In my case it is aan Absolute Layout. I've read the answers concerning those questions but I still don't get it.

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    AbsoluteLayout layoutbase = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutbase);       

    drawOval(); 

}
public void drawOval(){ //, int screenWidth, int screenHeight){ 
    AbsoluteLayout layoutbase = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutbase);     

    int screenWidth = layoutbase.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = layoutbase.getHeight();
    Log.i("MyActivity", "screenWidth: " + screenWidth + ", screenHeight: " +screenHeight);

    Coordinates c = new Coordinates(BUTTONSIZE,screenWidth,screenHeight);

    ...some code ...

    ((ViewGroup) layoutbase ).addView(mybutton, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(BUTTONSIZE, BUTTONSIZE, c.mX, c.mY));


    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showText(mybutton);
        }
    });
}

public void showText(View button){      

    int x = findViewById(LAYOUT).getWidth();
    int y = findViewById(LAYOUT).getHeight(); 

    Toast message = Toast.makeText(this, "x: " + x , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);       
    message.show();     


}
```

The `getWidth()` command works great in `showText()` but it does **not** in `drawOval()`. I know it looks a bit different there but I also used the `int x = findViewById(LAYOUT).getWidth();` version in `drawOval()`, and x/y are always `0`. I don't really understand why there seems to be no width/height at that earlier point. Even if I actually draw a Button on the Absolute Layout, `getWidth()` returns `0`. Oviously I want to measure the sizes in `drawOval()`.

Comment: Note that `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated and should never be used. use a density-independent Layout instead!

Comment: hi, thanks. but can I position elements absolutely in any other kind of Layout?

Comment: No, but to design something absolutely essentially means you are designing for one screen size/density. You should be able to achieve the desired result using something like LinearLayout (for example) and density-independent unit values ("dp" or "sp" instead of "px").

Comment: thanks again. I just want to put colored Ovals on the screen,clickable though. Do you think to use a "normal" layout is a good idea at all? ;) maybe the best way would be to draw on a canvas?!

Comment: oops... i thought this was more of a theoretical question about how views are drawn :). if your goal is to draw some shapes on the screen then yes, you should be creating your own custom class that extends View that can handle the work you want it to do. i'll post some samples below.

Answer (score 11):

*I think will help you.*

```
   LinearLayout headerLayout = (LinearLayout)findviewbyid(R.id.headerLayout);
    ViewTreeObserver observer = headerLayout .getViewTreeObserver();
            observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int headerLayoutHeight= headerLayout.getHeight();
        int headerLayoutWidth = headerLayout.getWidth();
        headerLayout .getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                this);
    }
});


}
```

Comment: what is "l" in your case? l.getHeight()

Answer (score 7):

`getWidth()` is giving you 0 because `onCreate` is called before layout actually happens. Due to views being able to have dynamic positions and sizes based on attributes or other elements (`fill_parent` for example) there's not a fixed size for any given view or layout. At runtime there is a point in time (actually it can happen repeatedly depending on many factors) where everything is actually measured and laid out. If you really need the height and width, you'll have to get them later as you've discovered.

Answer (score 3):

This specially deal with `Dimension`s so

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```

This may help you in managing dimensions.

Note: This returns the display dimensions in pixels - as expected. But the getWidth() and getHeight() methods are deprecated. Instead you can use:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

as also Martin Koubek suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to simply draw an oval on the screen, then consider creating your own custom `View` rather than messing around with `AbsoluteLayout`. Your custom `View` must override `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)`, which will be called when the view should render its content.

Here is some extremely simple sample code that might help get you started:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));
    }

    // create a nested custom view class that can draw an oval. if the
    // "SampleView" is not specific to the Activity, put the class in 
    // a new file called "SampleView.java" and make the class public 
    // and non-static so that other Activities can use it. 
    private static class SampleView extends View {
        public SampleView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);

            // smoothen edges
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4.5f);

            // set alpha value (opacity)
            mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);

            // draw oval on canvas
            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(50, 50, 20, 40), mPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android) also gives some sample code on how to draw a line if its helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

This give you screen resolution:

```
 WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
 Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
 Point outSize = new Point();
 display.getSize(outSize);
```

Comment: int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

Answer (score 1):

kabuko's answer is correct, but could be a little more clear, so let me clarify.

`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are (correctly) giving you 0 because they have not been drawn in the layout when you call them. try calling the two methods on the button after `addView()` (after the view has been drawn and is present in the layout) and see if that gives you the expected result.

See this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3591784/844882) for more information.

Comment: as i said earlier, however, i strongly suggest you use a different layout (such as `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`) as `AbsoluteLayout` is **not** density-independent and will not work well across multiple screen sizes and densities.

Comment: ...or if you are looking to draw an Oval on a Canvas, then just fill the screen with a custom-made view that can get the job done. see my code in my second answer below :)