# Is it possible in android canvas to validate the user drawing?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I want to set x and y coordinate points in the canvas and I want to validate whether the user is correctly drawing on the x and y coordinate points in canvas .Is it possible to validate the user drawing in canvas .Could some one please tell me any suggestion

Comment: what you mean with "validate"

Comment: For example, I am having a background image with dotted lines,now I want the user to draw on the dotted lines and I have to validate it whether it is correct or not? Is it possible in canvas and how can I proceed with this?

Comment: do you have the coords of the dotted lines?

Comment: No ,I just saw some questions and answers in this site and could not proceed without knowing it.Could you please help me out of this?

Comment: Do you have any sample program or any other link to refer this

Comment: I just got idea from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639165/android-user-paints-lines-with-his-finger?rq=1