# How can I write text on an oval shape

Tags: android, graphics, canvas

How can I inscribe line into oval using Canvas and Paint in Android?

UPDT:

I need something like that:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I assume you are trying to write text on top of an oval shape. Knowning the coordinates of the oval, use `Canvas.drawText` method at similar coordinates. If you're trying to draw a line, use `Canvas.drawLine` with similar coordinates

Comment: Solved with clipPath based on oval

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can inscribe a line into an oval with the methods available in the `Canvas` class. As for as my experience goes, you can only render straight lines. However you can draw oval with the `Canvas` class. I'm not sure what your primary goal is, but you might want to look up some Graphic libraries, that might over something like this.

**Update:**

Based on your provided image, I believe this is possible. You just need to find the two coordinates of the line: starting coordinate and Ending coordinate.

Once you have done this, [render the oval shape](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/04/draw-oval-on-canvas-canvasdrawoval.html) then
[render the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android) based on the two coordinates.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing the line with and oval mask.
u can rotate the canvas all you want to get the effects u need.