# Easy way to make a line graph from MySQL results in Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I need to make an activity that displays results from a MySQL query in a line graph. Does anyone know a tutorial for beginners or sample code I could look at to accomplish this? All of my results are going to be integers of 0-10 to keep things simple if that matters.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may get you started if you want to create a line graph from scratch:

[How to draw a line in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android)

It really depends how much of this work you want to do yourself.  You could probably find an open source line graph library somewhere as well.

Comment: [aChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) is a good one to check out.