# How to draw points at perticular location & draw line between those point with finger drag on it?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

I'm trying to draw two points on the screen & when i thouch the point1 and drag it to point2 a line need to be drawn from point1 to point2 .

as shown in below image
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Follow this code touch event for dragging

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

    start_x = event.getX();
    start_y = event.getY();     

  } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

    //create the line from start_x and start_y to the current location
    //don't forget to invalidate the View otherwise your line won't get redrawn

  } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

    //might not need anything here

  }
```

And for draw line follow this link
[How to draw a line in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android/5847729#5847729)

Comment: For this example i need to extend the Activity or view ?

Comment: You need extend Activity and implement OnTouchlistner