# How to draw lines on Android to show the path from one node to another?

Tags: android, dictionary, path, draw, routes

I need to create an application on android to show the paths from starting point to destinations but i have no idea about implementing a map image and pointing the destinations on it and also draw lines on an image to show the paths , can anyone give some examples about it and make some link suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this :
 [Draw a line in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android) and [Draw a line in Android](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/using-views-to-draw-lines-in-android/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry i am new here :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for Google Maps V2 with Polylines to draw your paths... [Google Maps Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Comment: İ will not work on Google maps , instead an image uploaded to the backround and lines on it.

Comment: In that case, you will want to use the 2D grahpics API. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html