# Flat infinate line?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I know that this is probably a very, very basic question but I'm very new. Basically I want to create a platform that my character can walk on. Almost like in the game "Flappy Bird" but, I want it to be a walkable platform. Is there any way I can create a "line" that stretches out infinitely. I've seen [this](http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/HillsBasic.jpg), but it's for iOS and isn't a flat line. I've tried researching, but I haven't seen anything that appeals to what I'm looking to achieve. Any help would be great. As a heads up I'm using `libGDX` Also leading me to any tutorials for something similar would be equally appreciated.

Comment: What are you drawing _into_?

Comment: So far it's just a blank screen I added to libGDX. @JustinJasmann

Comment: `Canvas` or `SurfaceTexture` or other?

Comment: A canvas. @JustinJasmann

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android

Comment: And that would work fine with libGDX? @JustinJasmann

Comment: If you're drawing to a `Canvas`, yes. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tutorial to create an exact copy of flappy bird

http://www.kilobolt.com/zombie-bird-tutorial-flappy-bird-remake.html

Could you modify this to create your walkable game?

Comment: That was one of the tutorial's I saw. But I'm simply trying to get a single line. As you can see here http://www.tuttoandroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Geometry-Dash-1-620x372.png . It's sort of rough, but that's one of the best examples I could find

Comment: This example gives you the structure and how to use libgdx. You should be able to edit as per your req.