# How to get the x and y value of a point?

Tags: android, point

I was working on making an android app and I have two points p1 and p2. Depending on what the user does, the location of the points will vary. For example they might be: 
`Point p1= new Point(123,123);`
`Point p2= new Point(234,686);`
I want to draw a line between these point. However when I checked what methods I could use for the point object, there was no method that would return just the x or y value of the point object. How would I draw a line between these two points then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a line in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x and y are public fields, you don't need a method to access them.

Also, Canvas.drawLine can take an array of points, so you don't need to read them if you're using that.

Answer (score 2):

Point class is simple as hell, `x` and `y` are public fields, so all what you have to do is:

```
int x = p1.x
```

Comment: heaven is simple,  hell is complex