# how do I build hexagons as buttons on android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

I'm developing a "settlers of catan" app and I got a big graphic problem: the game board contains a hexagons which have to be buttons. I searched on youtube but I didn't find any way to draw a hex button. 
Does anyone know how to build a hexagon button?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/benjakuben/ed67c1b9ac915cf27d2c  Try this.!!

Comment: You can draw hexagons as background with below code, but you will not be able to join the vertices of then, they will still occupy a square space.

Answer (score 1):

related to : [How to draw hexagons in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30218646/4345934) Try this class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class HexagonMaskView extends View {
    private Path hexagonPath;
    private Path hexagonBorderPath;
    private float radius;
    private float width, height;
    private int maskColor;

public HexagonMaskView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public HexagonMaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public HexagonMaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    hexagonPath = new Path();
    hexagonBorderPath = new Path();
    maskColor = 0xFF01FF77;
}

public void setRadius(float r) {
    this.radius = r;
    calculatePath();
}

public void setMaskColor(int color) {
    this.maskColor = color;
    invalidate();
}

private void calculatePath() {
    float triangleHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3) * radius / 2);
    float centerX = width/2;
    float centerY = height/2;
    hexagonPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius);
    hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY + radius/2);
    hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY - radius/2);
    hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radius);
    hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY - radius/2);
    hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY + radius/2);
    hexagonPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius);

    float radiusBorder = radius - 5;    
    float triangleBorderHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3) * radiusBorder / 2);
    hexagonBorderPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radiusBorder);
    hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY + radiusBorder/2);
    hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY - radiusBorder/2);
    hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radiusBorder);
    hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY - radiusBorder/2);
    hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY + radiusBorder/2);
    hexagonBorderPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radiusBorder);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c){
    super.onDraw(c);
    c.clipPath(hexagonBorderPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.save();
    c.clipPath(hexagonPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    c.drawColor(maskColor);
    c.save();
}

// getting the view size and default radius
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height =  MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    radius = height / 2 - 10;
    calculatePath();
}
}
```