# How to draw a line dynamically in Android layout

Tags: android, graphics, line, mindmapping

What I have done:

[image: Figure 1]

What I am looking for:

[image: Figure 2]

I do not care about design, but I do not know how to connect buttons to Main button with lines that are similar to the second image.
Note: I am creating buttons dynamically. Thus, I do not use XML file as I do not know how many lines/buttons I will have.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
    //
    RelativeLayout FirstLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.second_layou);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button yourButton = new Button(this);
    yourButton.setText("1");
    yourButton.setWidth(2);
    parms1.setMargins(w, h+250, 0, 0);
    FirstLayout.addView(yourButton, parms1);
    //
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button yourButton2 = new Button(this);
    yourButton2.setText("2");
    yourButton2.setWidth(2);
    parms2.setMargins(w-300, h+300, 0, 0);
    FirstLayout.addView(yourButton2, parms2);
    // and so on with other buttons
```

**Edit**:

**First**: When I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3616831/2131679) answer by adding this code at the end of `onCreate()`:

```
drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);
```

a line view is shown but buttons are gone! and I want the line to be drawn from the center of `MAIN` button to center of other buttons not from fixed points.

**Second**: when I add the same code before defining the buttons I got runtime error, and this is logcat:

```
01-29 15:25:25.956 26170-26170/com.example.user.raywenderlich E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                         Process: com.example.user.raywenderlich, PID: 26170                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.raywenderlich/com.example.user.raywenderlich.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.user.raywenderlich.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:46)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: your answer is from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3616831/4848308

Comment: "got run time error" - Then post your logcat

Comment: @g2o I mentioned that I tried this answer, I will edit the question to give you details

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.second_layou)` is returning null because it cannot find that id within the content view you have defined for the Activity. Probably because you have done `setContentView(drawView);`, which means `findViewById` won't work anymore.

Comment: I believe that is also a typo because you have `setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);` above it.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your patience! I got the problem, but how to merge the layout with the view to show the line along with buttons?

Comment: Just add your new view directly on your current one, don't completely replace it

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes `FirstLayout.addView(drawView)` worked, thank you a lot! lastly if you could help please, how to make the line starts exactly from center of `MAIN` button to center of other buttons or as in the image?

Comment: You might have to do some math with getX and getY. I don't really know

Answer (score 2):

I actually needed something similar and was bummed that there was no answer to this.

After some searching and combining of information I got to this state:

[image: Some textviews connected by curved lines.]

---

What I did was take a `FrameLayout`, so the `TextViews` could be stacked on top of the drawing `View`. I made a custom drawing `View` as suggested in this tutorial: [Basic Painting with Views](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Painting-with-Views).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root_layout">

   <com.dev.example.CustomDrawingView
       android:id="@+id/custom_drawing_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then I add the `TextViews` dynamically via code to the `FrameLayout` and use `Path` objects to draw the lines in the `CustomDrawingView`, from center to center of each `TextView`:

```
Path path = new Path();

int x1 = (int) firstView.getX() + firstView.getWidth() / 2;
int y1 = (int) firstView.getY() + firstView.getHeight() / 2;

int x2 = (int) secondView.getX() + secondView.getWidth() / 2;
int y2 = (int) secondView.getY() + secondView.getHeight() / 2;

path.moveTo(x1, y1);
path.lineTo(x2, y2);
```

Now the curve is made with the answer from this question: [How to draw a curved line between 2 points on canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432826/how-to-draw-a-curved-line-between-2-points-on-canvas)

Simply adjust the `curveRadius` in that answer to have different looking curves.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

---

**EDIT:** Oh and what's really important is to only call the `onDraw` method of the `CustomDrawingView` **after** all the layouts and views have been displayed. Because else the `TextView`'s `getX() & getY()` methods still return 0 and you won't see any lines.
The suggested position to start drawing them was in the `onWindowFocusChanged` method of an activity.

Comment: @Jaichander Don't have it on Github, sorry