# Create custom forms java android

Tags: android, image, canvas, imageview, polygon

I am editing an image and I must select a sector, for that I must be able to create forms using the touch and then paint that area

Here is an example of an edit app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must get touch position with something like this on your image view

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
return false;
}
```

Then you can add a custom view programmatically overriding onDraw method.
You can find a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android#answer-3616831)