# How to draw a line with mixed or multi color in android?

Tags: android

I don't need a solid line of drawings. I just need how to draw a line with mixed color or multi color in Android.

Comment: draw a piece of line with one color, other peace - with other color. This way you will get multi color line.

Comment: can you show us image what you want exactly ?

Comment: we can do everything in android just clear what exactly you want so we will suggest you how to do this

Comment: I want to draw a line with any mixed color like rainbow, using onTouchEvent in android.

Comment: did you want to change the color on selection of it ?

Comment: no, not change. When I first touch the screen, the color of line must be a mixed color. I can draw line with solid color, but I cannot draw line with mixed color.

Comment: Go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android You can change color and pass point from where to where you need x color. or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try this one

**multicolor.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
android:type="linear"
android:centerX="44%" 
android:startColor="#FF00ff00" 
android:centerColor="#FFFF0000" 
android:endColor="#FFffff00" 
android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

**line.xml**

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/multicolor" />
```

Comment: I want to know how to draw a line with onTouchEvent in java file, not the xml.