# drawing a path between start lacation and end location

Tags: android

I'm creating indoor location application using `arduino` and android studio. `Arduino` send the indoor location coordinate to android phone using `Bluetooth`. [image]

Create map using following java class

```
public class MazeCreator {

public static Maze getMaze(int mazeNo) {
    Maze maze = null;

        maze = new Maze();
    if(GameView.floorval== false) {
        boolean[][] vLines = new boolean[][]{
                {false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false}


        };
        boolean[][] hLines = new boolean[][]{
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {true, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, true},
                {true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, false, true},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true},
                {true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, true},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}
        };
        maze.setVerticalLines(vLines);
        maze.setHorizontalLines(hLines);
        Log.d("Maze 1=" ,Integer.toString(mazeNo) );

        if (mazeNo == 1) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(2, 7);
        }

        if (mazeNo == 2) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(2, 4);
        }
        if (mazeNo == 3) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(1, 3);
        }
        if (mazeNo == 4) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(0, 0);
        }
        if (mazeNo == 5) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(7, 1);
        }
        if (mazeNo == 6) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(8, 4);
        }
        if (mazeNo == 7) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(8, 7);
        }
    }

    else {

        boolean[][] vLines = new boolean[][]{
                {false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, true, true, false, false, true, true, false, false},
                {false, true, true, false, false, true, true, false, false},
                {false, false, true, false, false, true, true, false, false}


        };
        boolean[][] hLines = new boolean[][]{
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {true, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, true},
                {true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, false, true},
                {true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {true, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}
        };
        maze.setVerticalLines(vLines);
        maze.setHorizontalLines(hLines);

        if (mazeNo == 8) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(0, 0);

        }
        if (mazeNo == 9) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(1, 4);

        }
        if (mazeNo == 10) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(8, 8);
        }
        if (mazeNo == 11) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(4, 8);
        }
        if (mazeNo == 12) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(0, 8);
        }
        if (mazeNo == 13) {
            maze.setStartPosition(0, 0);
            maze.setFinalPosition(8, 3);
        }
    }
    return maze;
}
}
```

`current location` indicated by man and final location indicate from the blue color circle. now I want to `draw path` to `current location` to the final location. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

What about:

[How to draw a line in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android)

to draw your line. Activate it with onLocationChanged (I mean location listener), draw from last location to the new one (safe the old one in a variable) and overwrite it when you get a new position.