# How draw a horizontal line in a RelativeLayout without XML? (Android)

Tags: android, line, android-relativelayout

how do I draw a horizontal line in a relativelayout without create a class that extends View and without XML? I need to draw a simply line in a RelativeLayout in a given point of Cartesian plane

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432649/horizontal-1px-white-line-above-image-view-in-a-relative-layout?

Comment: @HarshSingal- this is through xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this:

```
View line = new View(this);
line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
line.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
layout.addView(line);
```

There are other ways too through paint.

Comment: I added line.setY(value) and replaced FILL_PARENT with MATCH_PARENT,now it works,thank you