# Android: TextView highlighting

Tags: android, textview, highlight, thin

just like a yellow highlighter pen. How can I draw a thin yellow line on the TextView text with round corner at both ends ?

thank you

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview

Comment: Are you asking about highlighting individual words or phrases? (Three people have already suggested the same link for adding a border...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradient and control it as you wish as follow :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF00" android:centerColor="#FFFF00"
         android:endColor="#FFFF00" android:angle="0" /> 
     <corners android:radius="30dp"  /> 
 </shape>
```

and in xml refer textview to that gradient as follow :

```
   android:background="@drawable/gredient"
```

hope help you.

Comment: thanks for your help. I initially used this but this is not what I expect because when the text in the TextView spans across several row, it is just a big round rectangle. What I want is highlighting pen over the middle of text. thanks anyway

Comment: @DayDayHappy i think if you add gradiant programmatically you can control its position