# "-type truecolorAlpha" does not work

Tags: imagemagick, png

I have some images whose type is `PaletteAlpha` and which have to be `TrueColorAlpha`. I am trying to use the command

```
convert testein -type TrueColorAlpha testeou
```

to do this conversion but the result is an image which still has `Type: PaletteAlpha`. Is this behaviour expected? How can I transform from one type to the other?

I have also tried things such as `PNG:testeou` but with no results.
My IM version is `6.7.8-9`.

Comment: PNG32:testeou should work.

Comment: Your version is pretty old.  The date printed is misleading; that's the date you built it.  ImageMagick-6.7.8-9 was released on 2012-08-10.  The current version is 6.9.1-4.

Comment: PNG32:testeou did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The PNG32: prefix forces the output PNG to be RGBA:

```
convert logo: -transparent white png32:logot32
identify -verbose logot32 | grep Type
  Type: PaletteAlpha
pngcheck logot32
  OK: logot32 (640x480, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced, 94.1%).
```

"identify" reports the "Type" of the image after it has been read in.  In this case, it is an image with transparency and fewer than 256 colors, so it's reported as PaletteAlpha.

"pngcheck" reports what's actually stored in the PNG file, which is RGBA.

In fact, "identify" also gives more information about the PNG file.  Near the end of the "identify -verbose" output can be found:

```
Properties:
...
png:IHDR.bit_depth       : 8
png:IHDR.color_type      : 6 (RGBA)
png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
png:IHDR.width,height    : 640, 480
...
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2015-06-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```