# Multi screen sizes in android

Tags: android

I am developing one android application for multi screen purpose.  I have read about multi screen support.  So i have to create some layouts layout-small,  layout-normal, layout-large, layout-x large. My doubt is, suppose i am having total 30 XML's, do i have to maintain all the 30 layouts in all the multi screen support layouts?  As well as do i need to maintain all images in other folders? Please suggest me the best way to do multi screen support.

I tried maintaining all the XML'S in all the layouts.

Comment: Try 9patch images, so that you may not need to use multi screens Check http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/22280925/4774515

Comment: You should try dynamic sizing for all android screens . Example - get screen size onCreate and change all the size of images depending on it .