# Android shape with gradient border and shadow

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable, android-shape

I have a png drawable for the buttons. But it image drawable has gradient and it looks bad when applying 9patch (gradient & 9patch non compatible). I want to do this with a shapes. But I can't drawing with android shapes because it's hard to me to understand it.

Can you help me to draw this image with a shapes?

[image]

It's contain a border gradient, orange rectangle inside with a rounded corners and shadow 120°

Comment: Use card view it will give the same output just set the corner radius

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use a cardview because I must use only drawable and only for a buttons

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round

Comment: Don't try what @NeelaySrivastava offered above. There is a simple button without a shadow.

Comment: lol its been 2 +yr since the answer was accepted bro @CoolMind

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava, :)))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here you go

#### Create your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#c8c0c0"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/my_rectangle">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Create my_rectangle.xml file inside drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#e95d11" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <size
                android:width="50dp"
                android:height="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

#### The result

[image]

#### Notes

1. I made it a 120 * 120 square, change the dimensions to make it rectangle
2. I made the radius of the rounded corner as 10dp, change it if you want
3. I made the padding as 5dp, you may change it as well

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much. Sad that I already published the app with the png 9patch. And it looks not perfect. But I hope your solution fix it and your shape works like a 9patch?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="180"
            android:endColor="@color/transperent"
            android:startColor="@color/quantum_orange" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        <size
            android:width="50dp"
            android:height="50dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is correct, better is using **9-patch**. See  [Creating & Using 9-patch images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124719/creating-using-9-patch-images-in-android), https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch, [How do I put a border around an Android textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-do-i-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview). Probably SVG-images can help, but I haven't succeeded. Also in the accepted answer shadows can be rotated by every 45 degrees, for instance, you can try 315 instead of 270.

You can use 9-patch tools. 'Draw9patch' tool disappeared from `sdk/tools` folder, but probably it is here: https://androidstudio.io/downloads/tools/download-the-latest-version-of-draw9patch.jar.html.

1. Copy an image (a border with a shadow) from your design.
2. Paste it in your image editor like Photoshop, Gimp.
3. Clear unneeded space with rectangle, magic wand tools.

[image]

4. Save the image as PNG and open [Simple nine-patch generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html).
5. Paste there the image and move rulers.

[image]

6. Download ZIP and extract it to `res` folder of your project.
7. Now you can use these `9.png` images as a shadow.

`9-patch` is easier to use than XML shadows with gradient and `CardView`. Shadowing in Android is horrible.