# How do I change background of Textview with XML

Tags: android, background, textview

I have a text view that currently uses Toast_Frame but I want to modify this and add my own twist and colors with an XML file. How can I do so? This is my current code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/message" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see for the background I am doing a Toast_frame and I want to change this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: textview.setbackgroung method ? tried this

Comment: I was trying to avoid that. I wanted to do it in XML and already have it send.

If I remember correctly something like android:background="@android:drawable/mybackfile"

Not sure

Comment: yes but in xml u dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a custom XML. Read the detailed documentation [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html). For example you can define `gradient`, `stroke` etc in the XML and use this custom drawable to to set the background.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">

      <gradient android:endColor="#CCCCCC" android:startColor="#CCCCCC"
      android:angle="270" />

      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#999999" />

      <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
      android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

Also see [How do I put a border around an Android textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview)

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comment above, you create a new drawable XML, "name_something.xml" and change your "toast_frame" to the new file.

In this new file you do as Shobhit Puri says, depending on how you want your background.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="opaque_red">#f00</color>
<color name="translucent_red">#80ff0000</color>
</resources>

Resources res = getResources();
int color = res.getColor(R.color.opaque_red);
textView.setBackgroundColor(color);
```