# Rounded corner for textview in android

Tags: android, textview, shapes, android-shapedrawable

I have a textview and want its corner to be in round shape. I already know it can be done using `android:background="@drawable/somefile"`. In my case, this tag is already included so cannot use again. e.g `android:background="@drawable/mydialogbox"` is already there to create image in background

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/mydialogbox"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

so when I want `textview(textview_name)` also with round corner, how this can be achieved.

Comment: Google have new framework,
new technologies is better 

[Jetpack Compose][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round/64087445#64087445

Answer (score 525):

1. Create `rounded_corner.xml` in the `drawable` folder and add the following content,

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >         
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="@color/common_border_color" />

      <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

      <padding
           android:left="1dp"
           android:right="1dp"
           android:bottom="1dp"
           android:top="1dp" />

      <corners android:radius="5dp" />
   </shape>
   ```
2. Set this drawable in the `TextView` background property like so:

   ```
   android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
   ```

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: The answer is correct just that the guy who posted did not explain it in detail. You need to create an xml [eg. rounded_view.xml]in your drawable folder with the above code. And in your layout surrounding your textview put this as a parameter  android:background="@drawable/rounded_view"

Comment: android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner" do not use extension here!

Comment: Add `android:shape="rectangle"` if it didnt work for you

Comment: And rebuild your project if it didn't work automatically

Comment: The xml code should be enclosed by `<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Comment: Helpful but not complete

Answer (score 58):

Beside `radius`, there are some property to round corner like `topRightRadius`, `topLeftRadius`, `bottomRightRadius`, `bottomLeftRadius`

Example `TextView` with `red` border with corner and `gray` background

**bg_rounded.xml** (in the drawables folder)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="#f00" />

    <solid android:color="#aaa" />

    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp" />
</shape>
```

**TextView**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded"
    android:text="Text"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    />
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 25):

With the Material Components Library you can use the [**`MaterialShapeDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable).

With a **`TextView`**:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        ../>
```

You can programmatically apply a `MaterialShapeDrawable`:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius);

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
        .build();

MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
ViewCompat.setBackground(textView,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

If you want to change the background color and the border just apply:

```
shapeDrawable.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.....));
shapeDrawable.setStroke(2.0f, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color....));
```

Comment: wish you had defined `R.dimen.corner_radius` properly for completeness.

Comment: I failed to use this in a RecyclerView Adapter.

Comment: @nyxee It is just a dimen (like 8dp).

Comment: Awesome answer ! @nyxee textView corner_radius is just a float ; set any value your want : float radius = 12f; for example.

Comment: Great one but how do I add the RGB colors? Dynamic one which I received as a String as data.

Comment: Would be nice to see the layout xml for this method as well

Answer (score 17):

Since your top level view already has android:background property set, you can use a `<layer-list>` ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)) to create a new XML drawable that combines both your old background and your new rounded corners background.

Each `<item>` element in the list is drawn over the next, so the last item in the list is the one that ends up on top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/mydialogbox" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/common_border_color" />

            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

            <padding
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 14):

**There is Two steps**

1) Create this file in your drawable folder :- `rounded_corner.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
         <corners android:radius="10dp" />  // set radius of corner
         <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff3478" /> // set color and width of border
         <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" /> // inner bgcolor
</shape>
```

2) Set this file into your `TextView` as background property.

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
```

**You can use this drawable in Button or Edittext also**

Answer (score 8):

create an xml gradient.xml file under drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="50dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#667162" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

then add this to your TextView

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the provided rectangle shape (without a gradient, unless you want one) as follows:

In `drawable/rounded_rectangle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <solid android:color="#00ff00" />
</shape>
```

Then in your text view:

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
```

Of course, you will want to customize the dimensions and colors.

Comment: how can we add a gradient please

Answer (score 7):

1. Right Click on **Drawable** Folder and **Create new File**
2. Name the file according to you and add the extension as **.xml**.
3. Add the following code in the file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="5dp" />
      <stroke android:width="1dp"  />
      <solid android:color="#1e90ff" />
  </shape>
```

4. Add the line where you want the rounded edge `android:background="@drawable/corner"`

Answer (score 6):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Put your TextView inside MaterialCardView:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/emergency_sms_template"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: It could be useful to add: app:strokeWidth="0dp" (to remove stroke edge)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVG for rounding corners and load into an ImageView and use ConstraintLayout to bring ImageView on TextView

I used it for rounded ImageView and rounded TextView

Answer (score -1):

> Simply using an rounded corner image as the background of that view

> And don't forget to have your custom image in drawable folder

```
android:background="@drawable/my_custom_image"
```