# How can I create such borders of the button?

Tags: android, user-interface

Could not post it without a link ! sorry !
[image]

Comment: Welcome to community. please be clear what you mean exactly.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded corner for textview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781902/rounded-corner-for-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a layer list drawable, something like this :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
  android:bottom="4dp"
  android:top="4dp">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="2dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@color/gray" />
  <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
</shape>
```