# Android Listview item's border

Tags: android, listview, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

I have one `ListView` and I have displayed an `ArrayList` of objects in my list. Each list item is a `TableLayout`. `TableLayout` has one `TableRow`. `TableRow` has 3 `TextView`s.

I want to show a border for the `TextView`s, so that my `ListView` will look like grid.

Can anyone tell me how can I set a border for `TextView`s in the `TableRow`?

Comment: Can you please refer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/

Comment: please past your code

Comment: Can you post some code with your layout and screenshot. @user2740599

Comment: why don't you use grid view?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use below code.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle" >

  <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#C0C0C0" />

<solid android:color="#C0C0C0" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
 </shape>
```