# How to display textview programmatically like below picture

Tags: android, textview

I want to display the text view like below picture I am searching finally I got the solution from this site  "https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout",but I do not know how to use this one.

How can I am using this one to display as my requirement?

[image]

Comment: i think this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3496315/1809221 can help you

Comment: hi please see i updated the answer, you can use flowlayout programatically

Comment: can you elaborate your question more properly like what your motive like is it related to the alignment, designing or what??

Comment: yes i want to display those elements progrmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing programmatically

```
FlowLayout
 inflater = (FlowLayout) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
FlowLayout ll = (FlowLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
FlowLayout tv = (FlowLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondlayout, null);
tv.setLayoutParams(new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ll.addView(tv);
setContentView(ll);
```

use it like this on layout

```
<org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout
                        xmlns:f="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.lopply.lopply"
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/content3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="230dp"
                        android:layout_height="190dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/title3"
                        f:horizontalSpacing="2dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/content3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/label_tip_3"
                            android:textColor="#5e5e5e"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblFacebook"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/label_tip_3_facebook"
                            android:textColor="#c64d31"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblAnd"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/label_tip_3_and"
                            android:textColor="#5e5e5e"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblTwitter"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/label_tip_3_twitter"
                            android:textColor="#c64d31"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblDot"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/label_tip_3_dot"
                            android:textColor="#5e5e5e"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />
                    </org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableLayout  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content >

<TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content>  <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/content3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_tip_3"
                        android:textColor="#5e5e5e"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblFacebook"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_tip_3_facebook"
                        android:textColor="#c64d31"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblAnd"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_tip_3_and"
                        android:textColor="#5e5e5e"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

 </TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content>    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/content3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_tip_3"
                        android:textColor="#5e5e5e"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblFacebook"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_tip_3_facebook"
                        android:textColor="#c64d31"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblAnd"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_tip_3_and"
                        android:textColor="#5e5e5e"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content>    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/content3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_tip_3"
                        android:textColor="#5e5e5e"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblFacebook"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_tip_3_facebook"
                        android:textColor="#c64d31"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblAnd"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_tip_3_and"
                        android:textColor="#5e5e5e"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

 </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Comment: i want to display those elements programatically.i dont want create in xml.

Comment: you can do the same by creating layout in java

Comment: Use TableLayout inplace of flowlayout and use tablerow in parent of tablelayout and add elements to tablerow

Answer (score 0):

Add FlowLayout.java class(Take from android-flowLayout project) in ur package. An try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FlowLayout _flowLayout = new FlowLayout(this);
    setContentView(_flowLayout);
    TextView _tv1 = new TextView(this);
    _tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    _tv1.setText("bvfjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjv");
    TextView _tv2 = new TextView(this);
    _tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    _tv2.setText("bvfjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjv");
    TextView _tv3 = new TextView(this);
    _tv3.setText("bvfjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjv");
    TextView _tv4 = new TextView(this);
    _tv4.setText("bvfjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjv");
    TextView _tv5 = new TextView(this);
    _tv5.setText("bvfjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjv");
    TextView _tv6 = new TextView(this);
    _tv6.setText("bvfjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjv");
    _flowLayout.addView(_tv1);
    _flowLayout.addView(_tv2);
    _flowLayout.addView(_tv3);
    _flowLayout.addView(_tv4);
    _flowLayout.addView(_tv5);
    _flowLayout.addView(_tv6);
}

}
```

Comment: hi thanks for replying me but i want create horizantally like showing in above picture,when i am using your post it will display vertically.

Comment: I tried this code, its working fine. Textviews displaying horizontally.Did u change anything?

Comment: hi,i am adding these text to arraylist,i want to delete the element what i touch  on flowlayout,how can i possible,i am not using any adapters.