# How to set border of Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing an Android app. And i am trying to show a `DashBoard.` DashBoard is working fine. I have taken gridview to display it, But **`I want to set the border of that gridview.`** How can i achieve it ? if anyone can suggest me something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override GridView drawing and draw border from there.

You can add rectangular shape as the background.

You can put your GridView inside another layout, set background color for that layout and set margin for the GridView. (not really good as Android has to draw big single-color view and then cover it with GridView)

Lots of ideas here: [How do I put a border around an Android textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview)