# Android panels/panes/islands

Tags: android, panels, panes

How do I make the boxes here around the text? Do I have to change from Relative- or TableLayout? Are they called panels?

[image]

Comment: Assuming I understand what you are asking, look into [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not have a simply border property, so you can create a border by background image. You can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496310/587110