# Border(like shadow) solid and large on TextView Android

Tags: android, textview, border

I am using that "hack".
I have read here in stackoverflow.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

But my border still smoothie,I wanna put a large and solid border on all my TextView (I already have my component extend a textview).

I have a selector in text color when I click in this text the text color need to change.(It was already working,but I tried to apply another alternative using canvas,in this alternative,I lost this comportment).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This page solve your problem, you can custom the style:

[How do I put a border around an Android textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview)

You can set a shape drawable (a rectangle) as background for the view.

```
<TextView android:text="Some text" android:background="@drawable/back"/>
```

And rectangle drawable back.xml (put into res/drawable folder):

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

You can use #00000000 for the solid color to have a transparent background. You can also use padding to separate the text from the border. for more information see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: not working, i wanna a border around the text, this code draw a rectangle border

Comment: like a shadow, but not smoothie

Comment: You question is not clean. Border around the text is a rectangle. Try to make more detailed picture (yours is a rectangle with something strange inside).

Comment: alredy have a picture with what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution (the hack) is working fine, you just have to tweak 2 parameters accordingly to get a better "solid" shadow effect.

### Parameters

The 1st parameter is the **shadow radius** of the `TextView`. This parameter decides how "wide" the blur (shadow) effect will spread behind your letter.

The 2nd parameter is the **repeat counter** of the for loop that wraps around your `TextView`'s `onDraw(...)` method. **Higher repeat count** will get you a more "solid" shadow by **trading off the performance**.

### "Solid" shadow

The rule here is, **increment on shadow radius (↑)** must always accompany with **increment on repeat counter (↑)** to achieve the "solid" shadow effect.

Similarly, if you want to **gain performance by reducing repeat counter (↓)**, you have to **decrease shadow radius (↓)** as well.

### Solid shadow `TextView`

```
package com.example.solidshadowtext;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SolidShadowTextView extends TextView {
    /**
     * Shadow radius, higher value increase the blur effect
     */
    private static final float SHADOW_RADIUS = 10f;

    /**
     * Number of times a onDraw(...) call should repeat itself.
     * Higher value ends up in more solid shadow (but degrade in performance)
     * This value must be >= 1
     */
    private static final int REPEAT_COUNTER = 10000;

    // Shadow color
    private static final int SHADOW_COLOR = 0xff000000;

    public SolidShadowTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SolidShadowTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < REPEAT_COUNTER; i++) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int color) {
        // Disable public API to set shadow
    }

    private void init() {
        super.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, SHADOW_COLOR);
    }
}
```

### Sample

[image: Solid shadow TextView]

Comment: I alredy try just up my count of repeat time, but i have one animation in layout with some text and that animmation become very slow in that way.
(and i try with just with 150x,  )