# Android : adding border around textview

Tags: android, textview, border

How to add border around text as shown in image using xml layout

[image: image 1]

I have tried adding border to layout but its overlapping with text.

[image: image 2]

Comment: you can use shape drawable

Comment: give textview's background as white and then put it above the box

Comment: can you please elaborate, i have to add textviews inside that rectangle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a border around an Android textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-do-i-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**You can try this layout, its reflecting as per your requirement**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Label 1: Value 1"/>

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Label 2: Value 2"/>

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Label 3: Value 3"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="   Details   "
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**xml of border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#cdcdcd" />    
</shape>
```

Hope this helps you somehow.

Answer (score 11):

To add a border to Android TextView we need to create an xml containing shape as rectangle file under drawable's folder and set it as background to the TextView.

```
<stroke> tag is used to set the border width and color.
```

**border.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke
android:width="2dp"
android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="10dp" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   >                               
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Android Programming is fun!!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to put a border to any layout instead of textview , make layout background as

```
**android:background="@drawable/border"**
```

Comment: its adding border over textview, i need to put couple of textviews inside that border rectangle.

Comment: Okay. Then you can make a design with any layout like linear or relative. Add border to that layout. Finally you can add textviews in that layout. Hope you got it.

Comment: not able to place textview over layout's border, pls check the new image in question

Comment: For to add that textview, you need to use framelayout.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

As we know ConstraintLayout is good and efficient performance wise so below is a code with ConstraintLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_user_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_with_circular_border"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/color_333333"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp"
                tools:text="FirstName LastName"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_user_name_title"
            style="@style/TextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            android:text="  Name  "
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: what is a rectangle_with_circular_border

Answer (score 1):

Create drawable file and add this code in that file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2px"
            android:color="@color/colorGreyBrown" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
```

then set this drawable file as a background to your textview

```
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Textview_register_als"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/foodynet_rounded_corner_brown_color_border_white_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/string_text_register"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGreyBrown"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_notificaiton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_effect_white"
        android:padding="16dip"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="22dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_createddateandtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="12dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iv_read_unread"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="Details" />

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post screen shot of layout, its not working as required

Comment: you can Change imageview to TextView as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
      textbackground.xml
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    

<item android:state_pressed="true">
<shape  >
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>
<corners 
android:radius="1dp"/>
</shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>
<corners 
android:radius="1dp"/>
</shape>
 </item>

<item android:state_focused="false" >


<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="#c38416"/>
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/bordercolor" />

<corners android:radius="3dp" />

<padding
    android:bottom="6dp"
    android:left="6dp"
    android:right="6dp"
    android:top="6dp" />

</shape>
 </item>

<item android:state_pressed="false" >
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="#c38416"/>
<corners 
android:radius="1dp"
/>
</shape>
```

```
 and
  <TextView
   android:background="@drawable/textbackground"

   />
```

Answer (score 0):

for others who have the same problem, you can use this `library`:

https://github.com/homayoonahmadi/GroupBoxLayout

It **doesn't use any `white` or other color backgrounds** for hiding border under the label

Also it supports `rtl` and `ltr` directions!

```
<ir.programmerplus.groupbox.GroupBoxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:padding="30dp"
    app:borderColor="@color/teal_700"
    app:borderCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:borderStrokeWidth="2.2dp"
    app:labelStyle="@style/GroupBoxLabel"
    app:labelText="Form Title"
    app:labelTextColor="@color/teal_700"
    app:labelTextSize="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</ir.programmerplus.groupbox.GroupBoxLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot from GroupBoxLayout]