# Xamarin.Android Button Border was not declared

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, colors, xamarin.android

I cannot set the `BorderColor` attribute to my `Button`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but Visual Studio says that the attribute was not declared. `Android:BorderColor` doesn't work either.

> The 'BorderColor' attribute is not declared

My code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:text="@string/header"
        style="@style/header_text" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/phones_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:background="@color/white"
        BorderColor="@color/gray"
        android:text="@string/phones"
        style="@style/button_style" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit your post include any relevant code as text, not an attached image.

Comment: Sorry. Just updated the question :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot set the BorderColor attribute to my Button.

You could refer to [@Konstantin Burov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-do-i-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview), set a shape drawable (a rectangle) as background for your `Button`.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/Button_Border"
    />
```

Create a rectangle drawable `Button_Border.xml` and put in in `Resource/Drawable` folder :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF4081"/>
</shape>
```

Effect :

[image]

## Update :

This is not a workaround, it' an answer, and there's no `BorderColor` attribute in `Android`. Please note that :

> Most Android views have attributes in the Android namespace. When referencing these attributes you must include the namespace prefix, or your attribute will be interpreted by aapt as just a custom attribute.

That's why it didn't work, and that's the reason your can deploy this project to your device with  no error.

Comment: This one works for me. Thanks, but it looks more like a workaround. I can't imagine that there is no other way to set the border of a button.

Answer (score 0):

> The 'BorderColor' attribute is not declared

The problem is IntelliSense could not pick up the attributes we type although those attributes are existing in Android SDK and show that the corresponding Attribute is not declared.

These are occurred due to missing of some *.xsd* files from XML schema folder in Visual Studio.

To fix this issue, download these files links given below :

- https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/android-layout-xml.xsd
- https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd

You can download and move these file manually to :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\XML\Schemas
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\XML\Schemas\1033
```

Comment: Hmm this solution looks like the better one, but it doesn't work for me. Are there any other .xsd files that might be missing?