# Why button's background color doesn't change in Android Studio

Tags: android, button, border, background-color

I am trying to change style of the button after clicking on it.
My plan: when user clicks on the button it change background color (orange -> white), border (none->orange border), text color (white->green).
But when I did it with drawable shape (for border as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview)), it changed background colour to orange (stroke color) and not to white (as I write for solid in shape and for `buttonPressed.setBackgroundColor` method in function `pressSemButton` just in case).
If I don't use drawable shape with border it works and background color changes to white.

My function for changing button's style:

```
public void pressSemButton(Button buttonPressed, Button button) {
        buttonPressed.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.orange_white_border));
        buttonPressed.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
        buttonPressed.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_dark));

    }
```

XML for orange_white_border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/orange_light"/>
</shape>
```

XML code for button in fragment's XML:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/firstSemesterButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text= "@string/buttonFirstSem"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />
```

What can I do to change background color of button to white with implementing orange_white_border for border on it?

Comment: I find stack**overflow** questions to work best when there is an explicit answerable question near the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the way you try to implement is a little outdated. There are many new libraries and features introduced with Material Design Library. I will describe step by step how to achieve to havee a button as in your question.

##### 1. Create a color resource folder

In Android Studio in the **Project** pane, right clik on the **res** folder and then select **new->Android Resource Directory**. From the window opened up, select **color** for the **Resource type**. A **color** directory will be created below the **res** folder.

##### 2. Add required colors in color resources

Now we need to have defined our colors in the color resource file as following:

```xm
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="material_orange_400">#FF3D00</color>
<color name="material_green_400">#00E676</color>
```

##### 3. Create color selector resources

Right click on the **color** folder we've added in step 1, choose **new->Color Resource File**. Make sure that the **root element** is `selector`.
Name the new file as **bg_selector** since it will control the background color. And repeat this step to create 2 more files and name them **stroke_selector** and **text_selector** respectively.
Here I will list the 3 files' content:

1. **bg_selector.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/material_orange_400"/>
</selector>
```

2. **stroke_selector.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/material_orange_400" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

3. **text_selector**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/material_green_400" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

These selectors are managed by Android automatically, so you don't need to set anything when a button press detected since we used the `android:state_pressed="true"`. The colors that are defined with this attribute will only be showed when the button is in the pressed state. for the rest of the states the second item's color will be shown by the system.

##### 4. Configure the button in your xml.

Now let's have a look at how our button should look like in the xml.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_first"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/bg_selector"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:textColor="@color/text_selector"
    app:cornerRadius="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:strokeColor="@color/stroke_selector"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

Altough the buttons' default style is Material, if somehow the attributes like `cornerRadius` and `strokeColor` does not appear, then make sure you set the button's style to `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` in order to make use of these attributes.

Finally you should get the following results:

For normal state
[image: normal state image]

For pressed state
[image: pressed state image]

Just exactly as you wish!

Comment: thanks for such a wonderful explanation!