# How to give border of cells in tablelayout in android

Tags: android

I have a question that how to give cell borders in tablelayout of Android programmatically.

**Here is my Code:**

```
 TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_Layout_List);
         TableRow row=null;
         TableRow row1=null;
         Button label = null;

         int size=items.size();
         for (int i = 0; i < size-2; i+=3)
         {
         row = new TableRow(SearchGridActivity.this);
         row.setId(100+i);

         for(j=0;j<3;j++)
         {
            /*TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                  new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                  (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            int leftMargin=10;
            int topMargin=2;
            int rightMargin=10;
            int bottomMargin=2;

            tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

            row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);*/
            if(count_img!=NUM_RESULTS)
            {
            //row.setPadding(10, 2, 10, 0);

            View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.tablecell, null);
            LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linear_table);
            /*MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = new MarginLayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);*/

            final ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

            img.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap[count_img]);
            img.setClickable(true);
            img.setId(count_img);

            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                         BaseInventoryItem item = items.get(img.getId());
                            if (item instanceof Offer) {

                                SearchResultActivity.list_flag = false;
                                grid_flag = true;

                                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchGridActivity.this, ProductComparisonActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("item", item);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            } else if (item instanceof Product) {

                                SearchResultActivity.list_flag = false;
                                grid_flag = true;

                                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchGridActivity.this, ProductComparisonActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("item", item);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                    }

                });
             BaseInventoryItem item = items.get(count_img);

             TextView txt_price = new TextView(this);

              if (item instanceof Offer) {
                  Offer offer = (Offer) item;
                  txt_price.setText(offer.getPrice().getPrice());
                  txt_price.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                  txt_price.setTextSize(15);
              } else if (item instanceof Product) {
                  Product product = (Product) item;
                  txt_price.setText("from " + product.getPriceSet().getMinPrice().getPrice());
                  txt_price.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                  txt_price.setTextSize(15);
              }



            lay.addView(img);
            lay.addView(txt_price);
            row.addView(v);
            count_img++;
            }
         }
         //row.addView(label);

         table.addView(row);


         }
        /* row1 = new TableRow(SearchGridActivity.this);
         row1.setId(10001);*/
         TableRow row2 = (TableRow) View.inflate(this, R.layout.tablerow, null);
         Button btn_load = (Button)row2.findViewById(R.id.btn_table_LoadMore);
         btn_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    NUM_RESULTS = NUM_RESULTS+12;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SearchGridActivity.this,SearchGridActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("keyword", keyword);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        /* row1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));*/
         TableRow.LayoutParams rowSpanLayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                 TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
         rowSpanLayout.span = 3;


         //row.setBackgroundColor(0xff222222);

        label = new Button(SearchGridActivity.this);
        label.setText("Load More");


        //label.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


         //row1.addView(label);

         //row.addView(label);

         table.addView(row2,rowSpanLayout);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

there is no direct way of doing this. you have to mess around with **background**, **margins** and **padding**.

i ended up using something like this

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ff0000">
<TableRow android:background="#00ff00" android:layout_margin="2dip">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:text="+" android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/label"  android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/amount"  android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
</TableRow>
```

taken from here. [LINK](http://www.droidnova.com/display-borders-in-tablelayout,112.html)

Comment: But Sam I am doing this with code not from hardcoded, Please suggest me the solution in respect of code not in hardcoded format. Thanks for your Response

Comment: the answer is same. you have to mess around with background, margins and padding. both in code or xml.

Answer (score 5):

Another two solution works, but not elegant.
My solution is to create in "drawable" new file, e.g. cell_shape.xml, with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
        <solid android:color="#0fff"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

In my code I have method which creates new cells:

```
private TextView initPlainTextView() {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
    textView.setPadding(CELL_PADDING, CELL_PADDING, CELL_PADDING, CELL_PADDING);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    return textView;
}
```

In other methods I do something like:

```
TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow(getContext());
rowHeader.addView(initPlainTextView("cell0"));
rowHeader.addView(initPlainTextView("cell1"));
tableLayout.addView(rowHeader);
```

PS: inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/7379990/1219241

Answer (score 1):

Layout parameters have also to be set programatically.

You can see the sample code below, this worked for me after creating the rows dynamically.

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,   
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent
);

tableRowParams.SetMargins(3, 3, 2, 10);

row.LayoutParameters = tableRowParams;
```

This fails on current Android SDKs as `row.LayoutParameters` is not visible.
Change it to:

```
row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
```