# Resources.getSystem() vs getResources()

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I am learning the SDK myself from resource available over the net.

I came across a situation now. I am trying the below code:

Type 1:`getResources().getString(android.R.string.cancel);`

Type 2:
`Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.cancel);`

Type 3:
`getString(android.R.string.cancel);`

All of the above methods return the same value. So what are these methods, what are their use cases. What are the good practices on when to use which method. Please help me out.

Answer (score 11):

The difference is not only in what you get, but in WHERE can you use them.

The first and the third ones are using "context." invisibly. So, very often (in static members or out of activity members) you can't use them directly, unless you pass context or resource as a static variable or as a parameter into your scope. But the second one

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.cancel)
```

You can use ABSOLUTELY EVERYWHERE in your application, even in static constants declaration! But for system resources only

Comment: It comes with a downside though. `Resources.getSystem()` provides access to only system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc).

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel Please, notice the last sentence of the answer. I absolutely agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

All 3 return the same value, but Resources.getSystem() references to the system resources and might cause a crash
 [if used incorrectly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535626/notfoundexception-when-looking-for-drawable-resource)

The advised usage is "getString(android.R.string.cancel);"

It is also used as such in the [WalkieTalkieActivity.java code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/src/com/example/android/sip/WalkieTalkieActivity.html) on the Android developer website.

Comment: yes i tried with   Resources.getSystem()  it gave me force in  some  places.. i recommend other two..

Answer (score 1):

These three methods are all the same.
Here is the root method : `getApplicationContext().getResource().getString("")` and here is shortcut method : `getString("")`
Use the shortcut method when you are processing on apps context.
In almost every case, we use `getString()` to get Strings defined in the String file.