# Resources inside Loader's loadInBackground()?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-context, android-loadermanager, android-loader

As far as I know, I can't hold reference to the activity's context inside a `Loader`.

Is there a safe way to get resources inside `Loader`'s `loadInBackground()` method?

Comment: Can't your sort it after the results are delivered to listeners (which then display the info)? I mean you cannot do UI updates in loadInBackground anyway.

Comment: @zaifrun Of course I can sort it later, but I wanted to do this in worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html#Loader(android.content.Context)) of the constructor of `Loader`:

> `Loader (Context context)`
>
> Stores away the application context associated with context. Since **Loaders** can be used across multiple activities it's dangerous to store the context directly; always use **getContext()** to retrieve the **Loader**'s **Context**, don't use the constructor argument directly. The **Context** returned by **getContext()** is safe to use across **Activity** instances.

And the implementation:

```
    public Loader(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    /**
     * @return an application context retrieved from the Context passed to the constructor.
     */
    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
```

So, within `loadInBackground()` you are free to get the resources from the context that `Loader` class retains, because it's an application context.

Comment: I know that Loader holds application context. But will context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.my_string)  return correct value?

Comment: Yep, it will. You do not necessarily need an activity context in order to fetch resources.

Comment: Didn't know that. If resources only need to have application context, I wonder why Resources class doesn't have static methods like getString() etc. It would be much simpler if we shouldn't pass context to the class/method every time we only want to get proper resource.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood you correctly, but there is such a method: [Resources#getString(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int)). Also, you may have a look at [`Resources.getSystem()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633539/1083957) API.