# android: how to display border of TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

how can i highlight the border of the tablelayout...
im using roundshape.xml which has shape as a background there must be some way by which i can give the border around your tablelayout...

roundshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="5dip" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:startColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

WhiteSmoke =#F5F5F5

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundshape"
         >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a table with borders in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108456/how-can-i-create-a-table-with-borders-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this might help u.. go through code u will figure out the trick

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundshape" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#ff9" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="this is amazing" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#ff9" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="this is amazing" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#ff9" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="this is amazing" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#ff9" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="this is amazing" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#ff9" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very similar post about this already here.

> From David Jesse
>
> My solution for this problem is to put an xml drawable resource on the
> background field of every cell. In this manner you could define a
> shape with the border you want for all cells. The only inconvenience
> is that the borders of the extreme cells have half the width of the
> others but it's no problem if your table fills the entire screen.

[Here is the reference to this resource.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7379990/427763)