# how to make a custom grid view like the image below in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

[image]

I need create an interface like the image in android.
Please help me.
thanks so much!!

Comment: yes, I know that, I should use tablelayout. But how can I get the separte between two columns and two rows like the picture.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mean you need a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)

Comment: yes, I know that, I should use tablelayout. But how can I get the separte between two columns and two rows like the picture.
Thanks

Comment: this post has a nice solution for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108456/how-can-i-create-a-table-with-borders-in-android

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing custom about this grid. You can use the standard grid with a SimpleArrayAdapter. Don't forget to set the correct number of columns.