# How to achieve table border in android for table layout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

i want to add border to table layout,but iam only able to add boreder to row in tablelayout ,i want to add coloumn border for table layout,But when i  try to add  layout margin to textview in tablerow it is not possible,find possible solution.

```
public class servicehistryload extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ServicehistryDetails>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ServicehistryDetails> doInBackground(Void... args0) {
            HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

            path.setNamespace();
            path.setUrl();
            path.setMethod_name("servicehistory");
            path.setSoap_action();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Webservice service = new Webservice(path.getNamespace(),
                    path.getMethod_name(), path.getUrl(), path.getSoap_action());
            try {
                SoapObject request = service.getRequest();
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = service
                        .getEnvelope(request);
                PropertyInfo senduserid = new PropertyInfo();
                senduserid.setName("userid");
                // senduserid.setValue(user.get(Session.User_Id));
                senduserid.setValue("adkl1");
                request.addProperty(senduserid);
                SoapObject response = service.getResponse(envelope);
                Log.i("Service History ", response.toString());
                if (servicehistdetaillst.size() > 0) {
                    servicehistdetaillst.clear();
                }
                int count = response.getPropertyCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);

                    ServicehistryDetails serhistdet = new ServicehistryDetails();

                    if(result.getProperty(2)!=null){
                        serhistdet.setSrno(result.getPropertyAsString(2));
                    }
                    else{
                        serhistdet.setSrno("");

                    }
                    if (result.getProperty(4) != null) {
                        serhistdet.setSessid(result.getPropertyAsString(4));
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (result.getProperty(7) != null) {
                        serhistdet.setVinno(result.getPropertyAsString(7));
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (result.getProperty(1) != null) {
                        serhistdet.setDealer(result.getPropertyAsString(1));
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (result.getProperty(3) != null) {
                        serhistdet.setServdate(result.getPropertyAsString(3));
                    } else {
                    }
                    if (result.getProperty(5) != null) {
                        serhistdet.setStatus(result
                                .getPrimitivePropertySafelyAsString("Status"));
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (result.getProperty(0) != null) {
                        serhistdet.setAction(result.getPropertyAsString(0));
                    } else {
                        serhistdet.setAction("N/A");
                    }
                    if(result.getProperty(6)!=null){
                        serhistdet.setTeklin(result.getPropertyAsString(6));
                    }
                    else{
                        serhistdet.setTeklin("");
                    }
                    serhistdet.setDetails("Details");
                    servicehistdetaillst.add(serhistdet);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return servicehistdetaillst;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(
                ArrayList<ServicehistryDetails> servicehistlist) {
            boolean alternateclr=true;
            servicehistorylist = new TextView[servicehistlist.size()];
            TableRow servicehistinnerrow = new TableRow(ServiceHistory.this);
            servicehistinnerrow.setId(10);
            servicehistinnerrow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            servicehistinnerrow.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);

            srno = new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
            srno.setId(1);
            srno.setText(R.string.servicehistrytabrowsrno);
            srno.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));

            servicehistinnerrow.addView(srno);
            sessid = new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
            sessid.setId(2);
            sessid.setText(R.string.servicehistrytabrows_sessId);
            sessid.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            sessid.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));
            servicehistinnerrow.addView(sessid);
            vinno = new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
            vinno.setId(3);
            vinno.setText(R.string.servicehistrytabrows_vinno);
            vinno.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            vinno.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));
            servicehistinnerrow.addView(vinno);
            deal = new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
            deal.setId(4);
            deal.setText(R.string.servicehistrytabrows_deal);
            deal.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            deal.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));
            servicehistinnerrow.addView(deal);
            teklin = new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
            teklin.setId(5);
            teklin.setText(R.string.servicehistrytabrows_teklin);
            teklin.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            teklin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));
            servicehistinnerrow.addView(teklin);
            servdate = new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
            servdate.setId(6);
            servdate.setText(R.string.servicehistrytabrows_servDate);
            servdate.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            servdate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));
            servicehistinnerrow.addView(servdate);
            status = new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
            status.setId(7);
            status.setText(R.string.servicehistrytabrows_status);
            status.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            status.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));
            servicehistinnerrow.addView(status);
            action = new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
            action.setId(8);
            action.setText(R.string.servicehistrytabrows_action);
            action.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            action.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));
            servicehistinnerrow.addView(action);
            dertails = new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
            dertails.setId(9);
            dertails.setText(R.string.servicehistrytabrows_details);
            dertails.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));
            dertails.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            String ss = dertails.getText().toString();
            servicehistinnerrow.addView(dertails);
            servicehistorttablay.addView(servicehistinnerrow,
                    new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            for (int i = 0; i < servicehistlist.size(); i++) {

                int leftMargin=10;
                int topMargin=2;
                int rightMargin=10;
                int bottomMargin=2;
                TableRow servicehistinnerrowvalues = new TableRow(ServiceHistory.this);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.setId(i);
                TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                          new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                          (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_border);
                /*if(alternateclr==true){
                    servicehistinnerrowvalues.setBackgroundResource(R.color.antiquewhite);
                    alternateclr= false;
                }
                else{
                    servicehistinnerrowvalues.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lemon);
                    alternateclr=true;
                }*/

                TextView seriano=new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
                seriano.setId(i);
                seriano.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                seriano.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                seriano.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                seriano.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                seriano.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.addView(seriano);

                servicehistorylist[i]= new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
                servicehistorylist[i].setTag(i);
                servicehistorylist[i].setText(servicehistdetaillst.get(i).getSessid());
                servicehistorylist[i].setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                servicehistorylist[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.addView(servicehistorylist[i]);
                TextView vinnumber=new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
                vinnumber.setId(i);
                vinnumber.setText(servicehistlist.get(i).getVinno());
                vinnumber.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                vinnumber.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.addView(vinnumber);
                TextView dealers=new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
                dealers.setId(i);
                dealers.setText(servicehistlist.get(i).getDealer());
                dealers.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                dealers.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.addView(dealers);
                TextView teklinears=new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
                teklinears.setId(i);
                teklinears.setText(servicehistlist.get(i).getTeklin());
                teklinears.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                teklinears.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.addView(teklinears);
                TextView servicedetail=new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
                servicedetail.setId(i);
                servicedetail.setText(servicehistlist.get(i).getServdate());
                servicedetail.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                servicedetail.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.addView(servicedetail);
                TextView stat=new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
                stat.setId(i);
                stat.setText(servicehistlist.get(i).getStatus());
                stat.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                stat.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.addView(stat);
                TextView actions=new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
                actions.setId(i);
                actions.setText(servicehistlist.get(i).getAction());
                actions.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
                actions.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.addView(actions);
                TextView details=new TextView(ServiceHistory.this);
                details.setId(i);
                details.setText(servicehistlist.get(i).getDetails());
                details.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                details.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                servicehistinnerrowvalues.addView(details);

                servicehistorttablay.addView(servicehistinnerrowvalues,
                        new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following [Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7379990/1292203)
Using a separate Layout and adding it to Table layout