# How to make table in android with border ?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to make the following screen as shown below:

> [image]

I searched the Internet, but couldn't find any useful resources.

Comment: I hope this link will be useful to you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003021/how-to-add-border-around-table-layout

Answer (score 0):

You require a combination of LinearLayout TableRow and ScrollView. Study my following code,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tbHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_list_reverse" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPartyID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/PartyID"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBookingDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/partyDate"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPartyDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/partyDate"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPartySales"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/partySales"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtOrder"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/partyOrders"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_column_normal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tbJan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="partyDetails" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtListPartyID"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".20"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/PartyID"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_holo_text"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtListBookingDate"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".20"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/partyDate"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_holo_text"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtListPartyDate"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".20"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/partyDate"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_holo_text"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtListPartySales"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".20"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/partySales"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_holo_text"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtListOrder"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".20"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/partyOrders"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_holo_text"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will give you output like below screen,

> [image]

Comment: To add a new row , then what have to be done by me ?

Comment: @osimerpothe sorry, I didnt get you.

Comment: Can you please see me that way to add a new row from code ? Also how can I separate columns by border ?

Comment: @osimerpothe the code will be dynamic according to your requirement. But you just need to create an object of TableLayout, TextView and set TextView into tableLayout using its addView() method.

Comment: What is the code for @drawable/gradient_bg_list_reverse.xml ?