# Create a border on an Android TableLayout similar to a HTML border?

Tags: android, xml, border, android-tablelayout

**Edit: I have seen this question [How can I create a table with borders in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108456/how-can-i-create-a-table-with-borders-in-android) and in fact the top answer is the solution I am using but has the problem in question.**

I have a `TableLayout` which I populate with lots of data dynamically. It is enclosed in a `ScrollView`

I wish to style it with a border so it looks like a spreadsheet. My solution thus far is to define a `<shape>` and surround the dynamically-created `TextView`s with the border. It works but you can see the discrepancy between the borders on each cell (each cell has it's own separate border). See image at the bottom.

Is there a better solution, so that it looks like one continuous spreadsheet?

Here is my XML for the table:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

        <TableLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tbl_statistics"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            >
        </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the XML for the border shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@color/material_blue_300" />
</shape>
```

And here is the code that dynamically generates the table:

```
    for(StatisticRowItem rowItem : rowItems)
    {
        //add a new row to the TableLayout
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView txtCol1 = new TextView(this);
        txtCol1.setText(rowItem.getItem1());
        txtCol1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_1dp);
        txtCol1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        row.addView(txtCol1);

        TextView txtCol2 = new TextView(this);
        txtCol2.setText(rowItem.getItem2());
        txtCol2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        txtCol2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_1dp);
        row.addView(txtCol2);

        tbl.addView(row);

        //add a new line to the TableLayout:
        final View vline = new View(this);

        vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
        //vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        tbl.addView(vline);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108456/how-can-i-create-a-table-with-borders-in-android

Comment: @David that is the solution that I am currently using

Comment: change TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT  to TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

Comment: Use android:layout_margin="1dp" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108456/how-can-i-create-a-table-with-borders-in-android

Comment: @PhươngTrần I see that he sets it in XML. I create `TableRow` in java code. how can I set it programatically? I see no `setLayoutMargin` or related method.

Comment: Check the following solution, it might be helpful.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108456/how-can-i-create-a-table-with-borders-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108456/how-can-i-create-a-table-with-borders-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

**you can change border with using layer_list**

[image: like this]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:padding="16dp"
>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tr_header"
    android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
   >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Book"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Author"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_unit_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unit Price"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tr_item_1"
    android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_product_item_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, Android, 4th Edition"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_author_item_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ed Burnette"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_quantity_item_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_unit_price_item_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$36.00"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price_item_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$72.00"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tr_item_2"
    android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_product_item_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="High Performance Android Apps"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_author_item_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Doug Sillars"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_quantity_item_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_unit_price_item_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$44.99"
        android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price_item_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$134.97"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tr_total"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/table_row_last_bg"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >
    <!-- layout_span is table column span -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_total_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total = $206.97"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />
</TableRow>
```

**res/drawable/table_row_bg.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="1dp"/>
      </shape>
    </item>
   <item
    android:left="1dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  </layer-list>
```

**res/drawable/table_row_last_bg.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

**res/drawable/table_cell_bg.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <!-- Draw a stroke/border around the rectangle shape -->
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Hide left, top and bottom side of
     rectangle with border using a solid color by padding right 1 dp -->
<item
    android:right="1dp"
    >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

[refer this link for more details](https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-tablelayout-in-android.html)