# How to change display data to table

Tags: java, android

I want to change the display format of data connected to this database in the form of tables in snippet .. how to implement in java activity ??

[image]

[image]

Example :

This is my source code :

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng(lat,longi))
.title(SITE_ID.get(i))

.snippet("Dapot Rev    Des 2017       Jan 2018       Feb 2018     MoM \n"
                                    +"Hadset 2G  "+Jml_Handset_2G_month1.get(i)+" "+Jml_Handset_2G_month2.get(i)+" "+Jml_Handset_2G_month3.get(i)+" "+Jml_Handset_2G_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Hadset 3G  "+Jml_Handset_3G_month1.get(i)+" "+Jml_Handset_3G_month2.get(i)+" "+Jml_Handset_3G_month3.get(i)+" "+Jml_Handset_3G_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Hadset 4G  "+Jml_Handset_4G_month1.get(i)+" "+Jml_Handset_4G_month2.get(i)+" "+Jml_Handset_4G_month3.get(i)+" "+Jml_Handset_4G_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Rev Voice   "+Rev_Voice_month1.get(i)+"     "+Rev_Voice_month2.get(i)+" "+Rev_Voice_month3.get(i)+" "+Rev_Voice_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Rev SMS     "+Rev_SMS_month1.get(i)+"       "+Rev_SMS_month2.get(i)+" "+Rev_SMS_month3.get(i)+" "+Rev_SMS_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Broadband   "+Rev_BBand_month1.get(i)+"     "+Rev_BBand_month2.get(i)+" "+Rev_BBand_month3.get(i)+" "+Rev_BBand_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Rev Digital "+Rev_Digital_month1.get(i)+"   "+Rev_Digital_month2.get(i)+" "+Rev_Digital_month3.get(i)+" "+Rev_Digital_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Rev GSM     "+Rev_GSM_month1.get(i)+" "+Rev_GSM_month2.get(i)+" "+Rev_GSM_month3.get(i)+" "+Rev_GSM_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Rev DCS     "+Rev_DCS_month1.get(i)+"       "+Rev_DCS_month2.get(i)+" "+Rev_DCS_month3.get(i)+" "+Rev_DCS_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Rev 3G        "+Rev_3G_month1.get(i)+"      "+Rev_3G_month2.get(i)+" "+Rev_3G_month3.get(i)+" "+Rev_3G_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Rev IR         "+Rev_IR_month1.get(i)+" "+Rev_IR_month2.get(i)+" "+Rev_IR_month3.get(i)+" "+Rev_IR_inc.get(i)+"\n"
                                    +"Rev All          "+Rev_ALL_month1.get(i)+"    "+Rev_ALL_month2.get(i)+" "+Rev_ALL_month3.get(i)+" "+Rev_ALL_inc.get(i)+""                            )
.icon(revicon));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7379990/9025311